Logged in but unable to get authenticated user
I have a problem getting whether the user is authenticated. I log in but the response I h=get is "User is not authenticated."
In my Api\AuthController I have this method to get the user:
public function login(LoginRequest $request)
{

    $data = $request->validated();
    $user = User::where('email', $data['email'])->first();

    if (!$user || !Hash::check($data['password'], $user->password)) {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => __('user-controller.incorrect_mail')

        ], 401);
    }

    $token = $user->createToken('auth-token')->plainTextToken;
    $cookie = cookie('token', $token, 60 * 24); // 1 day

    return response()->json([
        'user' => new UserResource($user)
    ])->withCookie($cookie);
}

//get the authenticated user
public function user(Request $request)
{
    return new UserResource($request->user());
}

I am trying to access is from here:
public function bookingInitiate(Request $request)
{
    $authCont = new AuthController();
    $authenticatedUser = $authCont->user($request);

    if ($authenticatedUser->resource) {
        // User is authenticated
        // perform some actions
        return $authenticatedUser;
    } else {
        // User is not authenticated
        // do something else
        return response()->json(['error' => 'User is not authenticated'], 401);
    }

When I use var_dump($authenticatedUser); it says "message": "Attempt to read property "id" on null" but I am logged in on my browser.
This is my api.php:
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    //Routes that require authentication go here...
    Route::get('/user', [AuthController::class, 'user']);
    // Password Update route
    Route::get('/validate-token', [AuthController::class, 'validateToken']);
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, 'logout']);
    Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
        Route::apiResource('staffs', UserController::class);
        Route::post('update-password', [AuthController::class, 'updatePassword']);
    });
    //Route::get('/check-auth', [UserController::class, 'isAuthenticated']);
});
Route::post('/booking/initiate', [TempBookingController::class, 'bookingInitiate']);

The booking functionality should work for either authenticated or non-authenticated users so there's no login required for that.
*I am not being able to add more tags than just PHP, there is a problem with SO. Yes I can login with the current code. Please do not edit this part, I will edit it later once I am able to comment.

Is this Laravel? If so please add the relevant tag to your post, then it's more likely to be seen by people with specific knowledge about that framework

Are you successfully loggedIn using the code you shared?

first of all DON'T use controllers within controllers, secondly where you do expect the authenticated user to be resolved from? Assuming you called login first and booking/initiate after. All you have done is make a request with an extra cookie. You have not included any middleware that can use this cookie to resolve an authenticated user.
